# Repeater and UpdatePanel change button backcolor on command

Tags: asp.net

I have an updatepanel with a repeater control with buttons inside of it.
I want when the user press a button to change the background color.
For now, the command executes fine but the color don't change.
Here is the aspx file.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updDocumentQuickView" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
  <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
             <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="wrap" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productName")%>' ForeColor="White" BorderColor="#b0003a" BackColor="#e91e63" Width="100" Height="100" Style="border-radius: 8px;" Font-Size="Medium" />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the code behind is

```
 Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    Dim btn1 As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("Button1"), Button)
    btn1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black
 end sub
```

but the color is not changing

Do you have something else?

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined your `UpdatePanel` with `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`, the panel won't be updated (meaning no change to its content will happen on the client side) until you call the `Update` method in code behind or define some Triggers for the `UpdatePanel`.

see [this resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel?view=netframework-4.8#refreshing_updatepanel_content) for more information.